# Not correct qx.ui.table.model.Remote

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I have a problem with qx.ui.table.model.Remote. I have two requests to the server, and take response nearly at the same time. And there is a state race. First response begin to process, but don't finish, then second response begin to process. And two responses have the same _firstLoadingBlock and write to the same place. And as a result we have empty rows in data table. 
Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem you are talking about in one complex UI. I can't remember exactly but it was related to some sort of interactive filtering of `qx.ui.table.Table` that was empty in one outcome of the race condition in its model's *count* requests.

If you can rewrite your code and avoid race condition it's the suggested way. If it's not possible Qooxdoo has a means to limit RPC request concurrency:

```
qx.io.remote.RequestQueue.getInstance().setMaxConcurrentRequests(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the responses in a queue, and have them start a callback processing the queue - but only if it's not already started? This would make sure responses are always handled sequentially.